# Find values that minimize weighted ratio errors

Tags: optimization

Let's say I am given

$\left \{ \phi_{ij}, \mu_{ij} \mid 0 < \phi_{ij}, \mu_{ij} \in \mathbb{Q} \wedge i,j \in \{1,..,n\} \right \}$

and I want to find or approximate

$\alpha_{1},..,\alpha_{n}$

such that

$\left | \sum_{\forall i,j} (\phi_{ij} - \frac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_j}) * \mu_{ij} \right |$

is minimal. Is there any (hopefully computationally inexpensive) way to achieve this?

Comment: What is this motivation? Does it relate Cech cohomology?